# C# Best method to sync contacts to AD

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am creating a small utility that will grab user data from a source. That user data includes Full Name and Email, this source will be changing (updating, creating and deleting users).

What is the best method to sync that information to AD. I feel that they way I'm doing is not the best/efficient way.

Right now I have code that deletes all the current contacts in the OU (Active directory on premise), and then all the contacts that exists gets added. This Sync utility runs every 30 minutes. There are about 300 contacts. On server, there is Recycle bin turned on, my other concern is that my current code will create a bunch of unnecessary objects.

I need to have the ability to: Remove contacts that are no longer at the source. Update any changes that have been done at the source (email update), or create new contacts.

I'm using C# System.DirectoryServices. The source has no way to trigger or send the information that is getting updated individually. I only have the ability to pull data from the source.

Comment: Deleting and then re-adding everything seems like a brute force approach, since you may end up deleting things that you simply add back. (There is also a problem if anyone tries to use the information before the sync is complete, since items will be missing temporarily). It would be better to (1) delete items that are no longer at the source, (2) iterate over the remaining items to check for any necessary updates, and (3) add any contacts that are net new. This is a pretty straightforward way of syncing two lists.

Comment: I agree, however, what would be the best way to achieve this programmatically (not asking for specific code, i just need a concept). Adding new is the easiest, All i have to do is check if the object exists on AD, if not then create. For update, i can check if exists, if it does, i can compare the mail property and update if different. But for Delete? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You know how to check if the object exists in AD. Can you not reverse that logic to check if an AD object still exists in the source?

Comment: I was thinking about this, the API of the source is very weird, but could theoretically be possible. I will try and update the status here later.

Comment: Personally I would break the problem down. Just get the full list from the weird API and store it in a C# object, then do the rest from there.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWu I was able to accomplish this part by doing a reverse lookup and deleting anything that doesn't exist. I now have a full Sync to AD utility, and it seems to work pretty good! It was basically divided in two/three steps. 1. check if user exists, if not create, if exists check for changes and update. 2. Delete AD objects that don't exist at source. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience and without language specifics it generally goes like this.

1. Index both source and destination to dictionary objects using a unique value that's common between them.
2. Remove items from the destination that are not present in the source.
3. Create any objects that are in the source, but not in the destination.
4. Reconcile the source information with the destination.  This is usually in the form of a loop where you can use the key of the source to reference, compare and change values at whatever level of granularity you need.

For steps 1 & 2 dictionary objects usually have methods to check if a key exists. so it should be straight forward to check and action when an object does or does not exist respectively.

I have a number of programs that synchronize information from/to various sources/destinations, including AD.  I know this isn't a PowerShell question, but I strongly suggest looking at the PowerShell [ActiveDirectory module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) (AD cmdlets).  There is an instancing capability that works really well for this sort of thing.

```
$ADUser = Get-User MrSmith -Properties "DisplayName"
$ADUser.DisplayName = "Bob Smith"
Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser
```

The instancing capability is naturally incremental, it will not rewrite the property unless it's different.  Having your objects stored in a hash makes it very easy to loop the source data, reference the destination object compare, report, reset apply etc...

Despite the functionality of the instance, I usually don't blindly assign the data.  This is mainly because I want to log what's changing. Nevertheless, this pattern has worked very well for me.